# VisualForce 'Submit' Not Working for SOME Users

Tags: visualforce

• We have a VisualForce page where users complete a form.  When they click 'Submit', an Opportunity Record is created in our org, and the user is re-directed to a 'Thank you. Your Submission was Successful' page. If Submit is not successful, there's an Error section below the Submit button that will detail there was an error (Usually this is due to a required field not being completed). Users both reported seeing errors and were able to go back and address them on the correct pages - Issue only seemed to be with submission itself.

• Multiple users have been submitting without reporting issues over the last two months.  However, Two users have reported not being able to submit our intake form (when 'submit' is clicked 'nothing happens') - One reported the Tech Rec Section (that renders based on previous user-selections within the form) did not render (which made me think a load-time issue on rerendering), but in the instance with the other user, The Tech Rec Section did render, as expected - It was just the 'Submit' function that didn't work for them.

• I've Checked out this page on improving VF performance, but I'm not sure this is the issue: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_performance.htm

• I've tested our page in multiple browsers (Chrome, Incog Chrome, Safari, Edge, Firefox) with no issues, and no load-time issues - Errors also visible in all instances.

• One user reported waiting 20 minutes after clicking 'Submit', and still 'nothing happened'. They reported not seeing any Errors.

• In both instances, I was able to complete the form from my computer, and it submitted without any lag nor issues. In both instances, the User confirmed I submitted the form and entered in values 'exactly as they had'.

• I'm not sure what else to troubleshoot here, nor am I sure about how to recreate the issue at this point, but I'm hoping someone here might have an idea as to what's going on?

• The Save function in the Apex controller is as follows:

```
   public PageReference save() {
    // Returns PageReference only on success
    if(this.ctrl.save() != null) {
        return Page.Congratulations;
    }
    // There was an error.
    return null;
}
```

• The Save/Error Handling within the VF Page is as follows:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" rerender="msgs" styleClass="submit action-button" style="width=100px" value="Submit" id="saveButton" />

    <div class="msgsdiv">
       <apex:pageMessages id="msgs"/>
     </div>
```

• SF Developer Notes mention for apex:pageMessages - "This component displays all messages that were generated for all components on the current page, presented using the Salesforce styling."

Comment: Since it is a custom VF, it  is possible that there are no error handling for certain types of errors. Therefore it is hard to guess without seeing code of page/controller. My advice would be to inspect that code and probably add in sandboxes in in submit method some code to throw exception/or other unusual behaviour to get closer to reproduce an issue

Comment: @kurunve - I think you could be correct - I've added the Error handling bits of my code above - Do you have any additional guidance on how I might be able to handle all error types?

Comment: You will need to set a debug log on the user to see if there are any Apex / Visualforce errors or unexpected results that are not surfacing in the UI.

Comment: @DavidCheng Yes - I'm in love with that idea. However, my issue is mainly with being able to recreate the issue in the first place to even be able to debug. :(

Comment: Are these users internal or external (if external, are you using Experience/Community Cloud?), and would you be able to login as one of the affected users to try and submit the form?

Comment: @VictorL. - These are external users.  The form is a fillable public-facing form, so it is accessible by 'guest users' at all times. There's no need for anyone to log in to access it, as it's open to anyone in the public to be able to submit an intake form for our services directly from our website.

Comment: One approach is to create a custom object for error logging, then build exception-handling around the Apex functions that are likely to cause errors (Data validation, DML statements,etc) and store the exception data in log entry.  But that won't catch any Visualforce markup problems or Javascript issues.